# VBA - Storing a range into a Range Property on a user class

Tags: vba, excel

I have a class that has the following definition:

```
Private pvtRngTest1 As Range

Public Property Get RngTest1() As Range
    Set RngTest1 = pvtRngTest
End Property

Public Property Set RngTest1(ByVal rng As Range)
    Set pvtRngTest1 = rng
End Property
```

When I'm using this class, I'm trying:

```
Sub FindAllTablesOnSheet(oSh As Worksheet)
    Dim oLo As ListObject
    For Each oLo In oSh.ListObjects
        MsgBox "Table found: " & oLo.Name & ", " & oLo.Range.Address
        Dim sr As SheetRanges
        Set sr = New SheetRanges            
        Set sr.RngTest1 = oLo.Range            
        MsgBox sr.RngTest1.Address
    Next
End Sub
```

I get an error:  Object Required (on the last line within the Next statement)

Can someone please help explain?   I believe I'm setting the Range property correctly, I get no error when I set it, but then I cannot access the Address of that property.

Comment: you have a typo ` Set RngTest1 = pvtRngTest`  ->  ` Set RngTest1 = pvtRngTest1`

Comment: if you used `Option Explicit` at the top of every module of yours you'd have caught it yourself

Comment: Great, thank you!    I'm now using it, to save another headache.

Answer (score 0):

As https://stackoverflow.com/users/3598756/user3598756 said above, it was typo.   Been about 10 years since I looked at VBA and overlooked the benefits of Option Explicit. :S